# redirect index.php to base url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, redirect

I have added a rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

By this the url doesn't contains index.php

But whenever I am going specifically to /index.php, I want to redirect to .  But then it results into too_many redirects.

The below code seems not to work

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

..

How I can achieve the same in the apache rules.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exmaple.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks @Sahadev . But my requirement are a bit different which I have found just now, below goes   the solution.

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Comment: We decided to go for different solution. Forget redirecting at web server level and just rely in a middleware which just detects that index.php in the url. In this case redirect (pretty simple preg_match() rule). Maybe suboptimal but simple.  I know this is not the answer you actually expect, but could be considered as a workaround.